# Normalize a dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose we have input vectors $x_i$ and $x_j$ where both are in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Then as the input vector dimension increases, the dot product between $x_i$ and $x_j$ increases. To normalize that, we can divide by the square root of the dimensionality $k$ of input vector  $x$ as follows:

$$\text{dotProduct} = \frac{x_i \cdot x_j}{\sqrt{k}}$$

How does the square root of $k$ above normalize the dot product?

Comment: How do you define $x_i$? The usual dot product $u\cdot v=\sum_{l=1}^ku_lv_l$ has an orthonormal basis $(e_i)_l=\delta_{il}$ satisfying $e_i\cdot e_j=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: @J.G. $x_i$ is a $k$ dimensional vector that can be random.

Comment: Ah, so $x_i\cdot x_j$ is also random. Could you specify the random distribution of $x_i$?

Comment: @J.G. Thank you. I will read the answer posted. But why is this assumption necessary please about how $x$ is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X=(X_1,\dots, X_k)$ is a random vector with $X_i$ centered iid, random variables with variance $\sigma^2=\mathbb{V}(X_1)$, then by the law of large numbers
$$
   \frac{\|X\|^2}{k} = \frac{X\cdot X}{k} = \frac1k \sum_{i=1}^k X_i^2 \to \mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\sigma^2
$$
So $\frac{X\cdot X}{\sqrt{k}} \sim \sqrt{k}\sigma^2$ alsmost surely.
On the other hand, if $Y$ is an iid copy of $X$, then by the central limit theorem
$$
   \frac{X\cdot Y}{\sqrt{k}} = \frac1{\sqrt{k}} \sum_{i=1}^k X_i Y_i \to \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^4)
$$
So in this sense two independent vectors "stabilize" in distribution with this normalization.

Comment: Thank you. One related question please. Why the growth of the dot product is by a factor of $k$, which is the dimensionality of the input vector?

Comment: Also, You mean $i$ in the sum or $k$ here $\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_i^2 \to \mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\sigma^2$? And you mean $\sigma^2 = \mathbb{V}(X_1)$ or $\sigma^2 = \mathbb{V}(X_i)$?

Comment: Can you please add a little bit more about how you concluded that $\frac{X\cdot X}{\sqrt{n}} \in O(\sqrt{n})$ almost surely?

Comment: @Avv sorry I royally screwed up the indexing. It was a bit late

Comment: @Avv $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ is defined to mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}<\infty$ i.e. $f$ grows slower than $g$. Although in this case it grows exactly as fast as $g$. So I should have written $f(n) \sim g(n)$ cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Comment: @Avv since they are independent *identically* distributed (iid), whether I define $\sigma^2 = \mathbb{V}[X_i]$ or $\sigma^2=\mathbb{V}[X_1]$ does not matter

Comment: You haven't stated enough assumptions for $X\cdot Y$ to be Normal, and your first display-line calculation makes it look like you're deducing the mean of $X_1^2$ and not expressing a distribution in terms of it.

Comment: @FelixB. Thanks for your patience. Regarding $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\sigma^2$ how did you come to this conclusion, please? Any why in the first line $\sigma^2 = \mathbb{V}(X_1)$ and not  $\sigma^2 = \mathbb{V}(X)$? Here did you assume that $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ as well or it's just a singler number with 1 dimension?

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \mathbb{V}[X]:= \E[(X-\E[X])^2]$ and I defined the $X_i$ to be centered. You can also consider uncentered random variables but this does not give you any more insight.